# Add images into string? Translate word into image

Tags: javascript, html, string, image, algorithm

I want to create a program that let you input a sentence such as:
I am happy.
And outputs: I am  (happy emoji, in my case an image I've created myself).

So far I am able to replace happy by another word but I need to replace it with an image. 
Can I add images to a string?
If so, how?

UPDATE: My code finally works, this is the html and javascript I've used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Parse emotional expressions with emoticions.</title>
     <style>
      .inline-img {
          height: 40px;
        }
    </style>
     </head>
      <body>
        <font size="+3" face="Helvetica">
       <p id="output"></p>
     </font>
         <script>
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
         function word_replace(replacements, str) {
           var result = str;
            for (var [x, url] of replacements) {
             result = result.replace(x, '<img src="' + url + '" alt="emoji" class="inline-img" />');
                    }
          return result;
          }
            var input = prompt('Input your sentence');
            var output = word_replace([

            [/(happy)/ig, 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4521/38517798662_418a72e9d9_b.jpg'],
            [/(sad|depressed)/ig, 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4553/38517797352_6c8fba1a3d_o.png'],
            [/(confused)/ig, "https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4519/37833334134_109952bda2_b.jpg"],
            [/(afraid)/ig, 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4516/37833334324_c43f01a30d_b.jpg'],
            [/(angry)/ig, 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4532/26773555349_63894fa4be_b.jpg'],
            [/(determined)/ig, 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4537/37833333874_ff92cb8647_b.jpg'],
            [/(love)/ig, 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4530/37833331724_8a90312ddb_b.jpg'],
            [/(indifferent)/ig, 'https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4543/37833333744_59da46444d_b.jpg']

          ], input);


          var outputElement = document.getElementById("output");
          outputElement.innerHTML = output;
      });

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to simply have the text displayed as HTML somewhere a simple modification to your replacement function will insert a `<img>` tag to the text.

This way all you need to do is provide a link to your images.

I changed your regex to include parenthesis in order to use the capture groups for the alt text of the `<img>` tags.

I also used a class to limit the height of the images with css.

```js
function mreplace(replacements, str) {
  let result = str;
  for (let [x, y] of replacements) {
    result = result.replace(x, '<img src="' + y + '" alt="$1" class="inline-img" />');
  }
  return result;
}

let input = prompt('Input your sentence');
let output = mreplace([
  [/(happy)/ig, 'https://icon-icons.com/icons2/860/PNG/512/happy_icon-icons.com_67810.png'],
  [/(sad)/ig, 'https://images.vexels.com/media/users/17482/106930/raw/fcba42ccb55e21d86c6cc25078f0431e-cute-and-sad-icon-vector.png'],
  [/(confused)/ig, "http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/157/196/bcf.gif"]
], input);

$("#input").html(input);
$("#output").html(output);
```

```css
.inline-img {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input"></div>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try doing it this way! 
I tried this in every possible way but your code doesn't seem to work...

Comment: Does the snippet above work for you? Are you getting any errors? Where are your images hosted, what happens when you run it? Does the text just not get replaced? Can you inspect the DOM to see if the <img> tags were inserted, can you see if the request for the images timed out (maybe your path to the images is wrong?).

Comment: It works now and I changed it so it works without Jquery. Also I have updated my question and inserted my final code in case anyone is interested. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to create ico font and use it to replace some words or etc..

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*
 * jQuery CSSEmoticons plugin 0.2.9
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Steve Schwartz (JangoSteve)
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Date: Sun Oct 22 1:00:00 2010 -0500
 */(function(a){a.fn.emoticonize=function(m){var c=a.extend({},a.fn.emoticonize.defaults,m);var d=[")","(","*","[","]","{","}","|","^","<",">","\\","?","+","=","."];var l=[":-)",":o)",":c)",":^)",":-D",":-(",":-9",";-)",":-P",":-p",":-Þ",":-b",":-O",":-/",":-X",":-#",":'(","B-)","8-)",";*(",":-*",":-\\","?-)",": )",": ]","= ]","= )","8 )",": }",": D","8 D","X D","x D","= D",": (",": [",": {","= (","; )","; ]","; D",": P",": p","= P","= p",": b",": Þ",": O","8 O",": /","= /",": S",": #",": X","B )",": |",": \\","= \\",": *",": &gt;",": &lt;"];var j=[":)",":]","=]","=)","8)",":}",":D",":(",":[",":{","=(",";)",";]",";D",":P",":p","=P","=p",":b",":Þ",":O",":/","=/",":S",":#",":X","B)",":|",":\\","=\\",":*",":&gt;",":&lt;"];var h={"&gt;:)":{cssClass:"red-emoticon small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},"&gt;;)":{cssClass:"red-emoticon small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},"&gt;:(":{cssClass:"red-emoticon small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},"&gt;: )":{cssClass:"red-emoticon small-emoticon"},"&gt;; )":{cssClass:"red-emoticon small-emoticon"},"&gt;: (":{cssClass:"red-emoticon small-emoticon"},";(":{cssClass:"red-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},"&lt;3":{cssClass:"pink-emoticon counter-rotated"},O_O:{cssClass:"no-rotate"},o_o:{cssClass:"no-rotate"},"0_o":{cssClass:"no-rotate"},O_o:{cssClass:"no-rotate"},T_T:{cssClass:"no-rotate"},"^_^":{cssClass:"no-rotate"},"O:)":{cssClass:"small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},"O: )":{cssClass:"small-emoticon"},"8D":{cssClass:"small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},XD:{cssClass:"small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},xD:{cssClass:"small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},"=D":{cssClass:"small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},"8O":{cssClass:"small-emoticon spaced-emoticon"},"[+=..]":{cssClass:"no-rotate nintendo-controller"}};var f=new RegExp("(\\"+d.join("|\\")+")","g");var n="(^|[\\s\\0])";for(var g=l.length-1;g>=0;--g){l[g]=l[g].replace(f,"\\$1");l[g]=new RegExp(n+"("+l[g]+")","g")}for(var g=j.length-1;g>=0;--g){j[g]=j[g].replace(f,"\\$1");j[g]=new RegExp(n+"("+j[g]+")","g")}for(var k in h){h[k].regexp=k.replace(f,"\\$1");h[k].regexp=new RegExp(n+"("+h[k].regexp+")","g")}var e="span.css-emoticon";if(c.exclude){e+=","+c.exclude}var b=e.split(",");return this.not(e).each(function(){var o=a(this);var i="css-emoticon";if(c.animate){i+=" un-transformed-emoticon animated-emoticon"}for(var p in h){specialCssClass=i+" "+h[p].cssClass;o.html(o.html().replace(h[p].regexp,"$1<span class='"+specialCssClass+"'>$2</span>"))}a(l).each(function(){o.html(o.html().replace(this,"$1<span class='"+i+"'>$2</span>"))});a(j).each(function(){o.html(o.html().replace(this,"$1<span class='"+i+" spaced-emoticon'>$2</span>"))});a.each(b,function(q,r){o.find(a.trim(r)+" span.css-emoticon").each(function(){a(this).replaceWith(a(this).text())})});if(c.animate){setTimeout(function(){a(".un-transformed-emoticon").removeClass("un-transformed-emoticon")},c.delay)}})};a.fn.unemoticonize=function(b){var c=a.extend({},a.fn.emoticonize.defaults,b);return this.each(function(){var d=a(this);d.find("span.css-emoticon").each(function(){var e=a(this);if(c.animate){e.addClass("un-transformed-emoticon");setTimeout(function(){e.replaceWith(e.text())},c.delay)}else{e.replaceWith(e.text())}})})};a.fn.emoticonize.defaults={animate:true,delay:500,exclude:"pre,code,.no-emoticons"}})(jQuery);



$('.comment').emoticonize();
```

```css
/*
 * jQuery CSSEmoticons plugin 0.2.9
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Steve Schwartz (JangoSteve)
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Date: Sun Oct 22 1:00:00 2010 -0500
 */
 
 /* Basic styles for emoticons */
span.css-emoticon {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS"; /* seems to give the best and most consistent emoticon appearance */
  font-size: 0.65em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
  width: 1.54em; /* note that this is a multiple of this span's font-size, not containing text font-size */
  height: 1.54em; /* so, relative to containing text, width and height are 0.9 x 1.6 = 1.44em */
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 1.34em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1.54em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.54em;
  border-radius: 1.54em;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  box-shadow: 1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  background-color: #ffcc00;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right top,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(255,204,0)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(255,221,85)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(255,238,170))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(255,204,0) 41%,
    rgb(255,221,85) 56%,
    rgb(255,238,170) 100%
  );
  -webkit-transition-property:color, background, transform;  
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s, 1s;  
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
}

/* Styles for two-character emoticons that need more letter-spacing for proportionality */
span.css-emoticon.spaced-emoticon {
  padding-left: 0.2em;
  width: 1.34em;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

/* This is a dirty dirty hack, because webkit doesn't properly do the padding+width=total-width as it should
   I think the width of the border may be throwing things off, because it's more noticable for small icons */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  span.css-emoticon.spaced-emoticon {
    width: 1.4em;
  }
}

/* Styles for emoticons that need to have smaller characters to fit inside the circle */
span.css-emoticon.small-emoticon {
  font-size: 0.55em;
  width: 1.82em;
  height: 1.82em;
  line-height: 1.72em;
  -moz-border-radius: 1.82em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.82em;
  border-radius: 1.82em;
}

span.css-emoticon.small-emoticon.spaced-emoticon {
  padding-left: 0;
  width: 1.82em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}

/* Styles for additional colors */
span.css-emoticon.red-emoticon {
  background-color: #eb0542;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right top,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(235,5,66)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(235,38,90)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(250,55,110))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(235,5,66) 41%,
    rgb(235,38,90) 56%,
    rgb(250,55,110) 100%
  );
}

span.css-emoticon.pink-emoticon {
  background-color: #ff8fd4;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right top,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(255,143,212)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(255,153,216)),
    color-stop(1,    rgb(255,173,225))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center right,
    rgb(255,143,212) 41%,
    rgb(255,153,216) 56%,
    rgb(255,173,225) 100%
  );
}

/* styles for emoticons that need no rotation, like O_o */
span.css-emoticon.no-rotate { 
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  font-size: 0.45em;
  width: 2.2em;
  height: 2.2em;
  line-height: 1.9em;
  -moz-border-radius: 2.2em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2.2em;
  border-radius: 2.2em;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right bottom,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(255,204,0)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(255,221,85)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(255,238,170))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(255,204,0) 41%,
    rgb(255,221,85) 56%,
    rgb(255,238,170) 100%
  );
}

span.css-emoticon.no-rotate.red-emoticon {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right bottom,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(235,5,66)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(235,38,90)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(250,55,110))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(235,5,66) 41%,
    rgb(235,38,90) 56%,
    rgb(250,55,110) 100%
  );
}

span.css-emoticon.no-rotate.pink-emoticon {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    right bottom,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(255,143,212)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(255,153,216)),
    color-stop(1,    rgb(255,173,225))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(255,143,212) 41%,
    rgb(255,153,216) 56%,
    rgb(255,173,225) 100%
  );
}

/* Styles for emoticons that need to be rotated counter-clockwise, like <3 */
span.css-emoticon.counter-rotated { 
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-box-shadow: -1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  box-shadow: -1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(255,204,0)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(255,221,85)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(255,238,170))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center left,
    rgb(255,204,0) 41%,
    rgb(255,221,85) 56%,
    rgb(255,238,170) 100%
  );
}

span.css-emoticon.counter-rotated.red-emoticon {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(235,5,66)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(235,38,90)),
    color-stop(1, rgb(250,55,110))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center left,
    rgb(235,5,66) 41%,
    rgb(235,38,90) 56%,
    rgb(250,55,110) 100%
  );
}

span.css-emoticon.counter-rotated.pink-emoticon {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    right top,
    color-stop(0.41, rgb(255,143,212)),
    color-stop(0.56, rgb(255,153,216)),
    color-stop(1,    rgb(255,173,225))
  );
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(
    center left,
    rgb(255,143,212) 41%,
    rgb(255,153,216) 56%,
    rgb(255,173,225) 100%
  );
}

/* Styles for animated states */
span.css-emoticon.un-transformed-emoticon, span.css-emoticon.animated-emoticon:hover {
    /* font-size: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    font-family: inherit; */
    letter-spacing: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    overflow: visible;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: none;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    border-color: transparent;
}

span.css-emoticon.nintendo-controller {
  font-size: .8em;
  height: 1.2em;
  line-height: 1em;
  width: 2.7em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
      linear,
      left bottom,
      left top,
      color-stop(0.09, rgb(116,121,140)),
      color-stop(0.55, rgb(165,170,189))
  );
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(
      center bottom,
      rgb(116,121,140) 9%,
      rgb(165,170,189) 55%
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment">
  Hi, this is a great plugin! :-)
</div>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

How about using https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/

Code example:

```js
function mreplace(replacements, str) {
  for (let [x, y] of replacements) {
    str = str.replace(x, s => `<i class="em em-${y}"></i>`);
  }
  return str;
}
let output = document.querySelector('#output');
let input = 'I want to be always happy, but never confused!';
let result = mreplace([
  [/happy/ig, 'blush'],
  [/confused/ig, "confused"]
], input);

output.innerHTML = result;
console.log(result);
```

```html
<link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet">

<p id="output"></p>
```